# Vb.net Text Splitting is Null

Tags: vb.net, split

I just separating line by line in a text file, with this code

```
Sub Event2()
    Dim Lines = File.ReadAllLines(Place + "Text.txt")
    Dim Srl As String = Lines.ElementAtOrDefault(1)
    Dim Str1() As String
    Str1 = Srl.Split("^")
    Title.Text = Str1(0)
    LoadIMage(pb1, Str1(1))
    LoadIMage(pb2, Str1(2))
    LoadIMage(pb3, Str1(3))
    TxtDesc.Text = Str1(4)
End Sub
```

But when the line is empty it is error, i try to added this code, but failed

```
If Srl.IsNullOrEmpty Then
```

What the code to ignore this sub when the line is Empty?

Comment: As you want to use `Str1(4)` you should check that `Str1.Length = 5`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try with:

```
If Srl IsNot Nothing Then
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(Srl)
```

It's a Shared method available on the String class, so you needn't have a valid String instance to call it on.